# Equivalent function to stringr::word in stringi package

Tags: r, stringr, stringi

I went through the `stringi` package manual to find an equivalent to the function `word()` in the package `stringr`, but I could not find it. The reason I am looking for it is because I want to set collation options for my locale  and `stringr` doesn't give me all the options that `stringi` does. Is there a function in the stringi package that does the same as the word() function in the `stringr` package? See the example below, where I want the next three words after the word "José", that is written in different ways. In the `stringi` package, the function `stri_opts_collator`allows to set the argument `strength=1` for a permissive collation strength, so all forms of "José" would have been taken into consideration.

```
sentencas<-c("josé é um trabalhador responsável","José é um trabalhador 
responsável","jose é um trabalhador responsável","Jose é um trabalhador 
responsável")

sentencas %>% word(2,sep=coll("jose ",ignore_case=T)) %>% word(1,3)
```

With `stringi`, I can extract all forms of "José":

```
stri_extract_first_coll(sentencas,"jose",strength=1).
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
sentencas %>% word(2,sep=coll("jose ",strength=1)) %>% word(1,3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the same as `stringr::word()`, but this would seem to do the trick:

```
sentencas %>% 
  stri_split_coll("jose ", strength=1, simplify = TRUE) %>% 
  .[,2] %>% 
  word(1,3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here another option. Please note, I have introduced some words before your marker word for extraction, i.e., "Josè", since I assume that you will not only have sentences starting with this word. The important functionality is the combination of using `stri_locate` for detecting the end of your marker word, adding one character position, and using this position with the last character position in your string to be passed to `stri_sub`. Please note, the function provided is not failsafe, e.g., for cases if there are zero matches, etc.

Please also check below benchmarks for the three solutions proposed so far.

```
library(stringi)
library(magrittr)

sentencas<- c("some words josé é um trabalhador responsável"
              ,"only one word José é um trabalhador responsável"
             ,"several words jose é um trabalhador responsável"
             ,"and again some words Jose é um trabalhador responsável")

stri_word <- function(marker, str, words_after_marker) {

  stri_sub(str,  cbind(stri_locate_first_coll(str, marker ,strength=1)[, "end"]+1, nchar(str)) ) %>% 
  { gsub( "^\\s+|\\s+$", "", stri_extract_first_regex(., paste0("(\\s\\w+){", words_after_marker[1], ",", words_after_marker[2],"}"))) }

}

stri_word("jose", sentencas, c(1,3) )

#[1] "é um trabalhador" "é um trabalhador" "é um trabalhador" "é um trabalhador"

#Benchmarks
library(microbenchmark)
library(stringr)

stringi_positions <- function() {

  stri_word <- function(marker, str, words_after_marker) {

    stri_sub(str,  cbind(stri_locate_first_coll(str, marker ,strength=1)[, "end"]+1, nchar(str)) ) %>%
    { gsub( "^\\s+|\\s+$", "", stri_extract_first_regex(., paste0("(\\s\\w+){", words_after_marker[1], ",", words_after_marker[2],"}"))) }

  }

  stri_word("jose", sentencas, c(1,3) )


}

stringi_map <- function() {

  sentencas %>%
    map(stri_extract_all_words) %>% 
    map(~{
      .x <- flatten_chr(.x)
      map(.x, stri_detect_coll, "jose", ignore.case=TRUE, strength=1L) %>% 
        flatten_lgl() %>%
        which() -> pos
      .x[(pos+1):(pos+1+3)]
    })


}


semi_stringi <- function() {

  sentencas %>% 
    stri_split_coll("jose ", strength=1, simplify = TRUE) %>% 
    .[,2] %>% 
    word(1,3)


}


microbenchmark(
  stringi_map(),
  semi_stringi(),
  stringi_positions()
)

# Unit: microseconds
#                        expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
# stringi_map()       3498.667 3752.886 4059.0339 4038.0925 4214.3480  7365.635   100
# semi_stringi()      485.543  558.966  805.0216  593.9015  652.7195 15806.567   100
# stringi_positions()  288.958  325.669  456.9946  344.6180  384.4865 10719.428   100
```

Answer (score 1):

`word()` is a pretty complex function with no single function equivalent in `stringi`. This is another way to achieve your desired results:

```
library(stringi)
library(purrr)

sentencas <- c("josé é um trabalhador responsável",
               "José é um trabalhador responsável",
               "jose é um trabalhador responsável",
               "Jose é um trabalhador responsável")

sentencas %>%
  map(stri_extract_all_words) %>% 
  map(~{
    .x <- flatten_chr(.x)
    map(.x, stri_detect_coll, "jose", ignore.case=TRUE, strength=1L) %>% 
      flatten_lgl() %>%
      which() -> pos
    .x[(pos+1):(pos+1+3)]
  })
## [[1]]
## [1] "é"           "um"          "trabalhador" 
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "é"           "um"          "trabalhador"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "é"           "um"          "trabalhador" 
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] "é"           "um"          "trabalhador"
```